# How can I retrieve the the current CSHTML file for more intelligent view selection?

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-partialview

Suppose I have a partial view "_Navbar.cshtml" in my Views/Shared folder that's referenced in a layout page... so it gets embedded on every page.

Now, suppose I have a view with the same name existing in my Views/ControllerX/Partial folder, which is a navigation bar specific to that view.

In this case, views in other controllers find the Shared partial view file fine.  However, when I run a view in ControllerX, the _Navbar.cshtml file in Views/ControllerX/Partial ends up usurping/overriding the one in Shared/Views.

So I was wondering if there's a way to prefer a view based on the currently executing cshtml file.  For example, if "Partial" is called from a cshtml file in the Shared folder, then it should prefer other partial views in that same folder over ones in more specific controller view locations.

In short, is there a way to rig the view engine so that rather than having a static search path order, it's contextual and looks for files in the same folder as the executing cshtml file first?

Comment: I'll completely override the RazorViewEngine.FindPartialView method if I have to, but in order to code this contextual intelligence, i need to know which cshtml file is requesting a partial view, so it can look for sibling files first, then files in the controller-specific view folder, and so on.  I think this would be a better default behavior anyway.

Comment: Someone suggested the @VirtualPath will display the path of the     CSHTML file....  http://stackoverflow.com/a/6311523/88409, but I don't know if that would be accessible once control flows into the HtmlHelper.Partial call.    VirtualPath is a member of WebPageExecutingBase, and I don't know if that's accessible from within the Partial handler.

Comment: Take a look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31302206/2181676 - That should also work with _Layout.cshtml file

Comment: That has the same effect, and is basically what I'm already doing.  That's a static routing order, which means when ControllerX is the origin of the action, it will always find the partial view under ControllerX/Partial, rather than shared, which is a problem for the layout, when the layout wants a view of the same name under Views/Shared.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you are trying to achieve. I'm pretty sure that if you set it up like the other thread I mentioned, then it will first look for /Views/{controller}/Partials/_Navbar.cshtml, if found it will return that, if not it will move to the next search path, and last it looks for /Views/Shared/_Navbar.cshtml - is this what you want?